# Using a pipe to input in an awk statement

Tags: linux, bash, awk, pipe

So I'm dealing with a file named cars, here's it contents:

```
toyota corolla 1970 2500
chevy malibu 1999 3000
ford mustang 1965 10000
volvo s80 1998 9850
ford thundbd 2003 10500
chevy malibu 2000 3500
honda civic 1985 450
honda accord 2001 6000
ford taurus 2004 17000
toyota rav4 2002 750
chevy impala 1985 1550
ford explor 2003 9500
```

I'm using grep to filter for lines containing a specific automaker and then piping that to my awk statement, and finally piping the final result to a new pipe with tee.

Here's the line of code I'm having trouble with:

```
grep "$model" cars | 
   awk '($3+0) >= ("'$max_year'"+0) && ($4+0) <= ("'$max_price'"+0)' | 
     tee last_search
```

I previously defined variables max_year and max_price as a user input in my script.

The file last_search is made but it's always empty.

Comment: What are `$max_year` and `$max_price`? You might do better to use `-v max_year="$max_year"`, etc. and then use `max_year`, etc. in awk and not need to play quoting games. In almost all cases `grep | awk` is unnecessary since you can do the same filtering in `awk` directly.

Comment: I previously defined variables max_year and max_price as a user input in my script.

Comment: Etan means awk -v max_year="$max_year" -v max_price="$max_price"  then lose all the extraneous quotes in the awk code block -- the part inside the { } characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly have something wrong with your variables, you should print them out and gradually build up the pipeline one command at a time to debug.

As it stands, it works fine for the following values:

```
$ max_year=2000
$ max_price=10000
$ model=a

$ grep "$model" cars
toyota corolla 1970 2500
chevy malibu 1999 3000
ford mustang 1965 10000
chevy malibu 2000 3500
honda civic 1985 450
honda accord 2001 6000
ford taurus 2004 17000
toyota rav4 2002 750
chevy impala 1985 1550

$ grep "$model" cars | awk '($3+0) >= ("'$max_year'"+0) && ($4+0) <= ("'$max_price'"+0)'
chevy malibu 2000 3500
honda accord 2001 6000
toyota rav4 2002 750
```

There are also better ways of doing it without having to manage your command string the way you have, since it's probably prone to errors. You can use:

```
grep "$model" cars |
  awk -vY=$max_year -vP=$max_price '$3>=Y&&$4<=P{print}'
```

(you'll note I'm not using the `string+0` trick there, GNU `awk`, which you're almost certainly using under Linux, handles that just fine, it will compare numerically if both arguments are numeric in nature).

Comment: I am sure you can remove `grep` in this solution.

Comment: @Jotne, not if you want the same functionality as the original, such as searching on make _or_ model, or looking for `al` to get the Malibu _and_ Impala, `<space>m[au]` for the Mustang _and_ Malibu, or even using `.` to get _all_ cars. That's why I wasn't so keen on Steven's answer since it locked the solution to matching only full model names, though not enough to override my sense of fairness and downvote him, of course :-)

Comment: awk can perform an unanchored non-field-specific match just as well as grep can. You cant to match a word as make or model? Use `-v model="$model" and then `$0 ~ model` in the awk script. Same for `/al/` and `/ m[au]/`. Though if you use a string literal for a pattern you do have to account for quoting differences correctly.

Answer (score 2):

```
set -a
model=malibu
max_year=2000
max_price=4000

awk '
$2 == ENVIRON["model"] &&
$3 >= ENVIRON["max_year"] &&
$4 <= ENVIRON["max_price"]
' cars |
tee last_search
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further to help Bob understand where he went wrong?